# Fedora 22 - touchpad detected but not working

Tags: drivers, fedora, gnome, touchpad

I am using fedora 22 (gnome) on a Dell Vostro 3558 - the touchpad is not working and I cannot figure out why.

It seems to be detected:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLLC6C1:00 06CB:796A                      id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

and I also see it in gnome settings - I can move the switch to on or off but it has no effect. I can't get the pointer to move unless I plug in a usb mouse.  I know this hardware is new (Spring2015) but my internet searches provide no help so I am guessing there is something simple wrong here.

I am running fedora 22 x86_64, log in with gnome (not wayland doesnt work there either).  Tried Fedora Live (22 and 21) with no luck.  It does work when I go into Setup, or if I boot a Windows install disk so I do know the hardware is not broken.

I was hoping for some help troubleshooting this.

FYI I asked this earlier [fedora 22 synaptics touchpad not working](https://superuser.com/questions/942960/fedora-22-synaptics-touchpad-not-working)

Edit 1: Somehow it worked after I played around with some xinput commands (which are not in bash_history unfortunately.  It worked through a few reboots until I powered off. Does not work anymore. What I do know is when working, xinput --list does not show the DLLC6C1:00 06CB:796A device (also detected as a touchpad).  Maybe the solution is to find a way to keep that device from being added?  usingf xinput --disable does not help.